# Why are my "NULL" datetime entries from tsv being converted to 0000-00-00 00:00:00?

Tags: mysql, csv, datetime, null, truncated

Recently updated to `mysql  Ver 8.0.19 for osx10.15 on x86_64 (Homebrew)`

I am trying to load data from a tsv file to add entries to an existing table. Everything seems to be working fine, except the values which are "NULL" (as in it literally says that, it's not empty) are being converted to 0000-00-00 00:00:00. There are no errors but I do get the warning"Data truncated for column 'beginexp' at row 2".

Here's what I've tried, to no avail:

```
ALTER TABLE infomegatask 
ALTER beginexp SET DEFAULT NULL; # same for field 'endhit'

ALTER TABLE infomegatask MODIFY COLUMN beginexp DATETIME NULL; #even though it was already nullable to begin with when I checked the schema

#also set sql_mode="NO_ZERO_DATE"
```

Here is a redacted snippet of what the tsv looks like (sensitive data has been obscured):

```
uniqueid    assignmentid    workerid    hitid   ipaddress   browser platform    language    cond    counterbalance  codeversion beginhit    beginexp    endhit  bonus   status  mode    datastring
XXXXX:YYYYY ZZZZZ   AAAAA   BBBBB   CCCCC   chrome  windows UNKNOWN 0   0   4.2 2020-04-22 16:32:24 NULL    NULL    0   4   live
```

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test/DB/tsv/infomegatask_round_9g.tsv' INTO TABLE infomegatask FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
Query OK, 24 rows affected, 13 warnings (0.21 sec)
Records: 24  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 13

mysql> warnings
Show warnings enabled.
mysql> show warnings
    -> ;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                        |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'beginexp' at row 2  |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'endhit' at row 2    |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'beginexp' at row 4  |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'endhit' at row 4    |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'beginexp' at row 7  |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'endhit' at row 7    |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'beginexp' at row 9  |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'endhit' at row 9    |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'beginexp' at row 10 |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'endhit' at row 10   |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'endhit' at row 14   |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'beginexp' at row 20 |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'endhit' at row 20   |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I mean the workaround I'm going with for now is to just update these zero datetimes to NULL, but it's a bit annoying and I would just like to figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In the [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) syntax you can convert columns.

So in your case:

```
  LOAD DATA
  INTO TABLE  xx ( .., @beginexp , ... )
  ...
  SET beginexp = IF(@beginexp='NULL', NULL, @beginexp),
  ...
```